# Use nested switch commands

Tags: javascript, nested, switch-statement

Trying to use nested switch commands to generate correct outputs on specific fields. In this specific example, the heading  value of basement, main floor or 2nd floor of a house depends on the number of house floors. I tried 2 different scripts but none of them has provided any output.

//1st script:

```
switch (this.getField("Floor Location").value) {

  case "-":
    event.value = "-";
    break;

  case "B":
    switch ((this.getField("Storeys").value)) {
      case "-":
        event.value = "-";
        break;
      case "One Storey":
        event.value = "11";
        break;
      case "Two Storeys":
        event.value = "17";
        break;
    }

  case 'M':
    switch (this.getField("Storeys").value) {
      case "-":
        event.value = "-";
        break;
      case "One Storey":
        event.value = "1";
        break;
      case "Two Storeys":
        event.value = "11";
        break;
    }

  case "2nd":
    switch (this.getField("Storeys").value) {
      case "-":
        event.value = "-";
        break;
      case "One Storey":
        event.value = "_";
        break;
      case "Two Storeys":
        event.value = "1";
        break;
    }
  default:
    event.value = this.getField("Floor Location").value;
    break;
}
```

// No output

//2nd script:

```
var TwoStoreys = storeys;
var floor = this.getField("Floor Location").value;
if (floor = "-");
var none = floor;
var storeys = this.getField("Storeys").value;
if (storeys = "-");
var zero = storeys;
if (storeys = "One storey");
var OneStorey = storeys;
if (storeys = "Two Storeys");
var TwoStoreys = storeys;

var floor = this.getField("Floor Location").value;
if (floor = "-");
var none = floor;

if (floor = "B");
var B = floor

if (floor = "M");
var M = floor

if (floor = "2nd");
var Second = floor;

switch (true) {
  case ((zero) && (none)):
    event.value = "-";
    break;
  case ((zero) && (B)):
    event.value = "-";
    break;
  case ((zero) && (M)):
    event.value = "-";
    break;
  case ((zero) && (Second)):
    event.value = "-";
    break;
  case ((Onestorey) && (none)):
    event.value = "-";
    break;
  case ((Onestorey) && (B)):
    event.value = "11";
    break;
  case ((Onestorey) && (M)):
    event.value = "1";
    break;
  case ((Onestorey) && (Second)):
    event.value = "-";
    break;
  case ((Twostoreys) && (none)):
    event.value = "-";
    break;
  case ((Twostoreys) && (B)):
    event.value = "17";
  case ((Twostoreys) && (M)):
    event.value = "11";
    break;
  case ((Twostoreys) && (Second)):
    event.value = "1";
    break;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Nested switch statements should work fine. Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Your scripts don't produce any output, they just set `event.value`. How are you checking this?

Answer (score 1):

1 - First Script

The lack of break statements:

```
switch (this.getField("Floor Location").value) {

    case "-": 
        event.value = "-";
        break;

    case "B":
        (this.getField("Store").value) {
            case "-": 
                event.value = "-";
                break;
            case "One Storey":
                event.value = "11";
                break;
            case "Two Storeys":                           
                event.value = "17";
                break;
        }
        break; //ADDED
    
    case 'M':
        switch (this.getField("Storeys").value) {
            case "-": 
                event.value = "-";
                break;
            case "One Storey":
                event.value = "1";
                break;
            case "Two Storeys":
                event.value = "11";
                break;
        }
        break; //ADDED
     
    case "2nd":   
        switch (this.getField("Storeys").value) {
            case "-": 
                event.value = "-";
                break;
            case "One Storey":
                event.value = "_";
                break;
            case "Two Storeys":
                event.value = "1";
                break;
        }
        break; //ADDED

    default:
        event.value = this.getField("Floor Location").value;
        break;
```

2 - Second Script

The use of `=` instead of `===` on the second script while using conditional statements was the major error, so you only need to change this, but I made this for you:

```
var floor = this.getField("Floor Location").value;
var storeys = this.getField("Storeys").value;
var zero, oneStorey, twoStoreys, none, B, M, Second;

if (storeys === "-") {
  zero = storeys;
} 
if (storeys === "One storey") {
  oneStorey = storeys;
}
if (storeys === "Two Storeys") {
  twoStoreys = storeys;
}

if (floor === "-") {
  none = floor;
}
if (floor === "B") {
  B = floor;
}
if (floor === "M") {
  M = floor;
}
if (floor === "2nd") {
  Second = floor;
}

switch (true) {
  case ((zero === storeys) && (none === floor)):
    event.value = "-";
    break;
  case ((zero === storeys) && (B === floor)):
    event.value = "-";
    break;
  case ((zero === storeys) && (M === floor)):
    event.value = "-";
    break;
  case ((zero === storeys) && (Second === floor)):
    event.value = "-";
   break;
  case ((oneStorey === storeys) && (none === floor)):
    event.value = "-";
    break;
  case ((oneStorey === storeys) && (B === floor)):
    event.value = "11";
    break;
  case ((oneStorey === storeys) && (M === floor)):
    event.value = "1";
    break;
  case ((oneStorey === storeys) && (Second === floor)):
    event.value = "-";
   break;
  case ((twoStoreys === storeys) && (none === floor)):
    event.value = "-";
    break;
  case ((twoStoreys === storeys) && (B === floor)):
    event.value = "17";
  case ((twoStoreys === storeys) && (M === floor)):
    event.value = "11";
    break;
  case ((twoStoreys === storeys) && (Second === floor)):
    // Please set the expected output for this case
    event.value = "YOUR_EXPECTED_VALUE";
    break;
}
```

Other recommendations:

1 - Group all declarations at the top of your code.

2 - Avoid duplicate variable declarations.

3 - Use === instead of == for comparison to avoid unintended type coercion.

4 - Provide a default value in your switch statement.

Comment: The 1st script works for oneStorey, but does not respond to twoStoreys. Is there any way to upload the pdf showing the  3 fields in question so that you can see the outputs?

Comment: I meant the 2nd script, not the 1st script.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an object to map between the values and forgo `switch` altogether:

```js
const map = {
  B: {
    "-": "-",
    "One Storey": "11",
    "Two Storeys": "17"
  },
  "2nd": {
    "-": "-",
    "One Storey": "_",
    "Two Storeys": "1"
  }
};

let floorLocation = "B"; //this.getField("Floor Location").value;
let storeys = "Two Storeys"; //this.getField("Storeys").value;

let result = map[floorLocation]?.[storeys];
if (typeof result === "undefined") {
  result = "-";
}

console.log(result);

floorLocation = "2nd";
storeys = "One Storey";

result = map[floorLocation]?.[storeys];
if (typeof result === "undefined") {
  result = "-";
}

console.log(result);

floorLocation = "-";
storeys = "-";

result = map[floorLocation]?.[storeys];
if (typeof result === "undefined") {
  result = "-";
}

console.log(result);
```

Note: I use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) so I don't have to worry about whether a floor location is defined. I could also remove the `"-"` entries too, since everything defaults to "-" anyway.

Comment: Obviously, I couldn't answer with working code because the question did not have working code, but the idea is sound, and the examples show that much.

Comment: Will the proposed commands work with pdf JS?

Comment: There is no mention of PDF in the question. I can make no guarantees one way or the other, having no way to test it.

Comment: How can I upload my pdf so that you can diagnose what is not working?

Comment: I don't know anything about the JavaScript used in PDF, so I'm not going to diagnose anything, no matter how you upload it. Ask a new question **and be sure to tag the question with [pdf]** and mention in the body of the question that the JavaScript will be used in a PDF scenario.